# Dynamically adjusting dataframe via a for loop optimization

Tags: python, loops, optimization

The below code is incredibly slow- i have over 300k thousand rows that it is applied to. Can anybody suggest ways to improve it

```
for i in range (1,len(df)):
    if df.loc[i,'match']==False:
        df.loc[i,'remaining_shares']=df.loc[i-1,'remaining_shares']-df.loc[i,'shares_traded']
        if df.loc[i,'remaining_shares']<0:
            df.loc[i,'remaining_shares']=0
            df.loc[i,'shares_traded']=df.loc[i-1,'remaining_shares']
    else:
        if df.loc[i,'remaining_shares']<0:
            df.loc[i,'remaining_shares']=0
            df.loc[i,'shares_traded']=df.loc[i,'starting_shares']
```

Comment: Please read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide sample df along with your explanation and expected output to improve your chances of getting a response

Comment: well there's definitely redundant code there.... `if df.loc[i,'match']==False:` and `if df.loc[i,'match']==True:` which can never evaluate as it's a sub-block.  an unneeded `loc`.  why not do in an `apply()`?

Comment: read up on [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html?highlight=shift#pandas.DataFrame.shift)

Comment: I tired the apply method, but i couldnt figure out how to amend a dataframe on the fly. the problem is that remaining shares is a column i need to have in the initial data so when i was just calling the row above, it wasnt taking an update value of the row. i am open to suggestion. also tried to use shift, but had the same problem.

Comment: @RobRaymond - can you suggest how to make the above loop utilizing apply such that the df is updated on the run